# Setting a ui:inputCheckbox to be checked in javascript

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputcheckboxes

I have a requirement to only allow system administrators to uncheck a checkbox on a custom lightning component.  I've included example code below that replicates some of the behaviour but I cannot work out how to set the value of the checkbox back to true if the alert is displayed.  Hopefully it's pretty obvious what I am trying to do from the code.  Just for your information the real component has the inputcheckbox inside a `<aura:iteration/>` so I don't think I can use anything like `document.getElementById()`.

Component :-

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="childCheckbox" value="true" change="{!c.onChangeChildCheckbox}"/>Test
</aura:component>
```

Controller :-

```
({
    onChangeChildCheckbox : function(component, event, helper) {

        // If the checkbox was unchecked by the user...
        if(!event.getSource().get('v.value')){
            var profileName = "Basic User"; // This would normally be set via a call to the controller class during initialisation (not implemented in this example)

            // If the user is not a system administrator, display alert & set the checkbox back to checked 
            if (profileName != "System Administrator"){
                alert("Not Allowed!");
                // PROBLEM - How to set the checkbox value to be checked. Code below doesn't work
                var temp = event.getSource();
                temp.value = true;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to call your code before calling the alert. I think the alert block your code execution. Also, if you want to get your checkbox html element to set the value you have to use: `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.getSource()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple change:

```
onChangeChildCheckbox : function(component, event, helper) {

        // If the checkbox was unchecked by the user...
        if(!event.getSource().get('v.value')){
            var profileName = "Basic User"; // This would normally be set via a call to the controller class during initialisation (not implemented in this example)

            // If the user is not a system administrator, display alert & set the checkbox back to checked 
            if (profileName != "System Administrator"){
                alert("Not Allowed!");
                // PROBLEM - How to set the checkbox value to be checked. Code below doesn't work
                var temp = event.getSource();
                temp.set("v.value",true); //******CHANGE HERE *****
            }
        }
    }
```

The getSource returns the element and thus you simply need to call `set` on that element

From the docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm

```
     //The following patterns are not supported
    //when you’re trying to access another component’s
    //DOM elements.
    var el = event.target;
    var currentEl = event.currentTarget;
```

> To retrieve the component that fired the event, use event.getSource()

Comment: @AndeeWork - Just updated as I forgot to put `temp.` before set in the code. Tested exactly as above and it works just fine